# Bayesian linear regression cost function

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression, bayesian

I am studying classification using linear regression . Now, I want to map it in Bayesian regression. Let talk about binary classification using linear regression again.

Assume that I have a set $X=${$x_1,x_2...x_n$} and binary lable $y$={$0,1$}.

Binary classification using linear regression task can embedded in to minimum loss function, where: $h(x)=ax+b$ is linear regression line. 
$$L=\sum(h(x)-y)^2$$
It is very clear fomular and discussed in [lecture note](https://class.coursera.org/ml-005/lecture/preview). Now I want to map it in Bayesian rule. Bayesian rule can express:
$$\max(p(y=0;1\mid X,a,b))$$
We have: $$p(y=0;1\mid X,a,b)=p(X\mid y,a,b)\cdot P(X)$$
Hence, the loss function with Bayesian classification case are given
$$L_{Bayesian}=\sum(p(X\mid y=1,a,b)\cdot P(X)-p(X\mid y=0,a,b)\cdot P(X))$$
Is the Bayesian's loss fomular correct? Thank you so much.

Comment: Your statement that p(y|X, a, b) = p(X|y, a, b)p(X) is totally wrong, please read [at least here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem). Also, you're confusing the task - your loss function is appropriate for training a linear regression, training a linear classifier is usually done using different loss functions (see [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) and [SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine))